# Macbook Pro speaker gets muffled

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

Macbook Pro 2016 15" model. The speakers often go from perfectly clear to very noticeably muffled when adjusting the volume. It often happens when turning the volume up - but it'll still be at reasonable levels. It gets muffled immediately as opposed to slowly degrading in quality which leads me to believe it's not a problem with the speaker slowly deteriorating.

It usually goes away after a few restarts.

Is this normal? How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced this issue and after a complete re-install and every troubleshooting regarding software tried out, I handed it in at an AASP. They determined the issue to be hardware, and exchanged the top case (which also means no more sticky keys).

So my best advise is, take a backup and go visit your local AASP.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this problem for quite a long time, at some point it hit me that, this probably something to do with with driver, since switching frequency on midi settings fixes temporarily

I've been using [eqMac](https://eqmac.app/) ([github](https://github.com/bitgapp/eqMac)) a system wide equalizer which installs it's own drivers seems like solving the problem
[image: Eq mac screenshot]

Comment: addendum: I was way too fast to conclude, it is not resolving the issue completely, although, still better than system drivers, I think.